# Understanding Faster R-CNN

Tags: neural-network, convolution, object-detection, faster-rcnn

I'm having some trouble understanding the way the Faster R-CNN algorithm works. Specifically, the way the authors describe the concept of anchors.

In their paper from [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1506.01497) they describe anchors in the following way:

> At each sliding-window location, we simultaneously
>   predict multiple region proposals, where the number
>   of maximum possible proposals for each location is
>   denoted as k. So the reg layer has 4k outputs encoding
>   the coordinates of k boxes, and the cls layer outputs
>   2k scores that estimate probability of object or not
>   object for each proposal. The k proposals are parameterized relative to k reference boxes, which we call anchors. An anchor is centered at the sliding window
>   in question, and is associated with a scale and aspect
>   ratio (Figure 3, left). By default we use 3 scales and
>   3 aspect ratios, yielding k = 9 anchors at each sliding
>   position. For a convolutional feature map of a size
>   W × H (typically ∼2,400), there are W Hk anchors in
>   total.

I can't wrap my head around this. How do you incorporate the fixed scales (128x128, 256x256, 512x512) and aspect ratios (1x1, 1x2, 2x1) (which they mention later), into this, when they also predict the bounding box with its parameters x, y, width and height in the reg layer for each anchor?

Comment: The k (9) anchors of fixed sizes and scales are the inputs of the reg layer, and for each anchor it regresses an output bounding box (a proposal). This is done for every location in the image downsampled by the anchors' x and y stride (to avoid doing that operation on each pixel).